# Ext JS - how to pass arguments to listener present in controller from view

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a view - a panel basically ...
i have menu buttons in it ..... 4 menus inside a button ... i want to call one particular function present in the controller each time but with different parameters ... how is it possible ?

```
xtype: 'button',
menu: {
  items: [{
    text : 'menu 1',
    listeners: {
       click: 'controllerfunction' //with argument 1
    }
  }, {
   text : 'menu 2',
    listeners: {
       click: 'controllerfunction' // with argument 2
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268977/passing-arguments-to-listener

Comment: I tries to do this way @RIYAJKHAN . Everything is in declarative way ..there is no launch function in my view...when i use scope : this inside my listener , that does not point to my controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following:

```
xtype: 'button',
xtypeToOpen:'listView', // This is the argument.
id: 'btnListView',
text: 'List'
```

and

```
xtype: 'button',
xtypeToOpen:'gridView', // This is the argument.
id: 'btnGridView',
text: 'Grid'
```

and

```
'button[id$=View]': {
    click: this.onClickViewBtn
},
```

and

```
onClickViewBtn: function(btn) {
    var centerContainer = this.getCenterContainer(),
        item = centerContainer.down(btn.xtypeToOpen); // Here I use the argument.
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, I've also added another answer that doesn't force the OP to change the style of listening (the declarative way)

Answer (score 12):

Alexander's way works, but there is another way that is more in the same style you were using.

```
xtype: 'button',
menu: {
  items: [{
    text : 'menu 1',
    listeners: {
       click: {fn: 'controllerfunction', extraArg: 'yes'}}
    }
  }, {
   text : 'menu 2',
    listeners: {
       click: {fn: 'controllerfunction', extraArg: 'no'}}
    }
  }]
}

// In your controller
controllerFunction: function(event, target,options) {
    if (options.extraArg === 'yes') {

    }
}
```

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15c7

Comment: Thanks for this solution ... I searched so much before asking this question and this is a really clean solution .. !!!